# In Windows 10, Google Chrome keeps muting itself in volume mixer

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, audio

I'm on Windows 10 and just recently I've noticed that Google Chrome starts off muted in the volume mixer and needs to be manually un-mute. When left alone for a while, Chrome automatically mutes itself again.

Here is how it looks in the Volume Mixer:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipyBY.png]

I have uninstalled and re-installed Google Chrome and it did not fix this issue. All solutions of this issue on the internet say that I need to do something with Google Toolbox, which I don't even have installed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks to me that the problem isn't Google Chrome - it is Windows 10 muting all but the two it thinks that are part of the O/S.  I think you have found a bug.  Have you tried Opera or IE to see if they act the same?  Look to the right side of this screen.  Apparently you are not alone.  That are not all Win10, either.  Maybe it really is a Chrome bug.  But try some of the others and see how they act.  This has never happened to me on my Win7 or Win8 machines.

Comment: This article says Micro$oft is trying to discourage Chrome entirely:  https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/05/windows-10-s-edge-bing-default/

Comment: Oh my, this makes me nuts. And today, had more volume slider than fit in the window, and I didn't realize that I had to scroll window to see the  mixer sliders that were invisible to the right. Even though I know to look for this issue, I didn't notice the scrollbar and it took me ten minutes to get some youtube audio to play.

Comment: Here is some information, but my Chrome is already set to allow sites to play sound - https://www.howtogeek.com/324568/how-to-automatically-mute-new-tabs-in-chrome-and-firefox/

Comment: I found that having Adobe Premiere Pro open will turn down the volume of Chrome to zero in windows Volume Mixer.  Not sure why...   but worth quitting any other apps / services and see if any of them affect the volume behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with several workarounds :
[Issue 95435 - Chrome automatically mutes itself in Windows repeatedly](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95435).

I list the workarounds that worked for some (but never for all) :

- Disabling and re-enabling the Google Toolbox extension
- Uninstalling the extension Fast Free Converter
- In `chrome://plugins/`, disable
  `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32_11_9_900_117.dll`
  and enable the one on `C:\C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\`
- Deleting the file `NPSWF32_11_9_900_117.dll`
- Uninstall GigaClick Clawer via Control Panel -> Programs and Features.

There seem to be many causes for this problem.
If none of the above solutions apply to your case,
you might check if an extension is responsible,
by starting Chrome in
[Incognito Mode or Safe Mode](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/chrome-incognito-mode-safe).
If this solves the problem, disable/enable extensions one by one
until you find the one.

Comment: Hmm. I cleaned up all my chrome extensions. I didn't have any of the culprits named in this list, but removed any that I no longer used audio or seemed audio related.I thought it was fixed, but then the problem occurred again. In my case I think I may be able to correlate the issue to my behavior. I think the problem occurs after I unplug USB headphones. I'll double check. But I think Chrome is doing me the favor of muting itself when headphones are removed so my speakers don't blast. But, I do plug in and remove my headset many times a day as I switch between speakers and headphones.

Comment: Do the headphones unmute if plugged in again? And have you tried Chrome in Incognito Mode?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I spent some time this morning trying to figure out a repeatable pattern to make my mute tab problem occur, but with no luck. It still occurs, but not as often as before. Perhaps Windows 10 version 1803 update changed things (Audio options are now integrated into win10 settings?). Perhaps cleaning out old Chrome extension changed things. I don't know. If I'm able to figure out how and when this mute tab issue occurs, I'll post a new question and update here.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/419128/I+have+no+sound+on+Chrome.) worked for me:

1. Open the Control Panel → Sound → Speakers → Advanced
2. Un-check "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device"
3. Open Volume Mixer while playing audio in chrome
4. Unmute Chrome

Comment: This almost seems like a devious attempt at pushing the Edge browser. It took me a while to find the solution... Usually I just opened Edge for convenience sake. I asked another question so that the solution is easier to find: https://superuser.com/questions/1515398/how-to-enable-chrome-audio-in-windows-10

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you try reinstalling the Sound Card driver.

1. Go to **Device manager** and right click on the sound card driver (look in the Sound, Video and Game Controller group) then click **Uninstall**.
2. **Reboot the PC** and it should reinstall the driver automatically. (If it doesn't you can just download and install the driver from the manufacturer's website.)

Comment: what is this suggestion based on? All audio works fine.

Comment: @MichaelLevy: Do not change drivers if you don't absolutely have to.

Comment: @harrymc - Agreed. I wasn't planning on it since everything works fine.

Comment: I think this answer negatively impacts the mission of superuser.com to collect and distribute knowledge